# Crontab not executing script with cURL

Tags: php, curl, cron

I have a cron that's set to run every ten minutes that works fine if I execute the file manually by entering

```
php register.php
```

But, my cron will not execute this file once it includes anything `cURL` related. My cron is as follows

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/register.php
```

I know that the cron is getting the correct file because at the very top of it, I put php's mail function to send me an email so that I know it was executed. But, anything cURL related will not execute. There aren't any global variables or server variables in the script, so that isn't the reason. I've checked both the crontab and the php error logs and nothing is there pertaining to this issue.

Comment: Might sound like a dumb question, but how can I specify root user execution in the cron?

Comment: I'm not sure. I don't get mail with an error message from crontab

Comment: As a user. `crontab -e`. No `sudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this at the beginning of your script:

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Comment: Though your answer wasn't exactly the correct one, per se; it lead me in the right direction. It was indeed a directory problem. I have no idea why when the cron executed the file, the directory changed. I've been using crons for quite some time and I've never ran into a problem like this.